# Is it possible to do a one-night D&D (or similar) session in just a few hours with only three people?

Tags: game-recommendation

My flatmate is big D&D fan, but we two other flatmates are not particularly interested (though not averse either.) Can we two inexperienced flatmates set up a role-playing game, have it be fun for all and also conclude in an evening? Ideally what I'm looking for is a pre-canned scenario so we can effectively not need an experienced DM (or even a DM at all.)

Don't mind buying books, materials etc as needed. Don't mind learning the ropes but we're not going to gain DM exp quickly so we still need help keeping this simple. I looked at how to [plan a fun one off session](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/how-to-quickly-plan-a-fun-one-off-session) but it seems we'd need to be more experienced to get the benefit of this advice.

Comment: what kind of game are you looking for? Fighty? Story?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And since you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)! We may be able to help workshop the question more there.

Comment: Probably story - adventure is good, can be absurd/humour though. Fantasy/sci-fi don't mind. Prefer not horror.

Comment: Great, I'll get on the chat and see if anyone wants to talk through this, thanks.

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible. (Auto Insert Test)

Comment: I'll reopen after clairification and workshopping has been edited into the question.

Comment: @BenParsons I look forward to it!